# DialogModule.forRoot() TypeScript error

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

**Property 'forRoot' does not exist on type 'typeof DialogModule'**

I'm recreating the first "Angular Service" demo from the DialogModule documentation and am getting this error.  The kendo-angular-dialog version is 0.20.0 based in an Angular 4.0.0 project created via the Angular CLI tool as described in the Kendo - Getting Started documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue with 0.20.0. A possible workaround is to install 0.19.0 which has the forRoot() signature:
npm install @progress/kendo-angular-dialog@0.19.0 --save

Answer (score 0):

The `forRoot` method is no longer needed in version 0.20. All examples in the [Angular Service help topic](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dialog/service/) have been updated to reflect this, and it is [noted in the changelog](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dialog/changelog/).